# Inject generated port with webEnvironment = RANDOM_PORT in a property file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

We can bootstrap a server started in a random port by using `webEnvironment = RANDOM_PORT`. For instance:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = RANDOM_PORT)
```

In case we want to access to the port, we can use `@LocalServerPort Integer port` and the port will be injected.

I have a case where actually I need to obtain the port but inside the `application-test.yml` file. I would like to do something like this:

```
myHost: http://localhost:${localServerPort}
```

I found no way to do this. Do you know how I can solve this problem?

Comment: `YML` files are processed during context initialization process, possibly very well before `localServerPort` is even assigned. So It is not possible to access that variable in `YML`. However, if you want, you can provide server port via environmental variable instead of using a random port, since environment variables can be accessed in `YML` files.

Comment: @KedarJoshi I using environment variables, however I'm trying to solve a problem I have with spock. It looks like spock when spying an object is creating the object with a copy of the initial properties, so I cannot modify spied objects on runtime.